# Retrieving a Pointer Column in Parse.com

Tags: io, parse-platform

I have two classes miaEvents and miaLocations. On miaEvents I have a column Pointer-type named "locationEvent".I'm triying to retrieve the data from that column. This is how I'm doing it.

```
__block NSString *myString;

    PFObject *obj = [self.event objectForKey:@"locationEvent"];
    [obj fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            myString = [object objectForKey:@"Name"];
        }
    }];



        NSLog(@"Name %@", myString);
```

My output returns "Name (null)" . Not sure why its this happening. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because fetchInBackgroundWithBlock performs the request asynchronously.

You have to move

```
NSLog(@"Name %@", myString);
```

in the callback block of fetchInBackgroundWithBlock if you want to display/make use of the fetched object:

```
__block NSString *myString;
PFObject *obj = [self.event objectForKey:@"locationEvent"];
[obj fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        myString = [object objectForKey:@"Name"];
        NSLog(@"Name %@", myString);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Yeah, but How can I use that variable outside the block?

Comment: You don't. You have to make use of it inside the block. Basically there is no point in creating the myString variable outside the block.

Comment: Don't forget that when querying miaEvents you can specify that you want to include the object of the relation locationEvent. This will spare you to fetch it later.

Comment: You should have a look [in the parse documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-pointers/iOS) at Objects/Relationnel Data, starting from "By default, when fetching an object, related PFObjects are not fetched."
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you man, I included the query on PFQuery from my Table and it worked perfectly.

Thanks

Comment: You are welcome! You should set your question as answered now.